# How can I check for multiple entries in a relational database?

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

For example, write a query to show the students with more than one class.

```
myQuery :=
    (project studID (select (count(studID) > 1)(schoolRoster)));
```

Assume that schoolRoster contains the studID and classID of every student registered for a class (so it will have a duplicate studID if that student is registered for more than one class).

What I need is for it to display the student ID's of only those students who have more than one class, but my count data structure doesn't work. Can you help me know what I would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out with the help of a co-worker. I hope it will help someone else. To do this you need to make a copy of the query and manipulate the data like in the code below.

```
myQuery :=
    project studID, classID (schoolRoster);
myQueryCopy(studID2, classID2) :=
    myQuery;
checkMoreThanOne(ID) :=
    project studID(select studID = studID2 and classID <> classID2(myQuery product myQueryCopy));
% At this point you could be done, but if you need additional information from the original table, you can get it with one more line of code (myQueryFinal)
myQueryFinal :=
    project studID, studAge (select ID = studID (checkMoreThanOne njoin schoolRoster));
```

Comment: I realize that having a students age in the schoolRoster table would not be done in a well formed DB, but I have tried to simplify things.